# I don't know if I put the egde template engine correct or did something wrong

Tags: javascript, express

I am following a few steps of a tutorial to learn. But when I put this step, this step is when i start the edge framework.

steps: 
npm init
npm i startbootstrap-clean-blog
npm i express
npm i nodemon
and i put some code on my main index.js, create some folders .
------------>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>index.js

```
const path = require("path");
const expressEdge = require("express-edge");

const express = require("express");
const app = new express();

app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(expressEdge);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.render("index");
});

app.get("/about", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "pages/about.html"));
});

app.get('/contact', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'pages/contact.html'));
});

app.get('/post', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'pages/post.html'));
});

app.listen(4000, () => {
    console.log("App listening on port 4000")
});
```

Error messages from console:

```
/home/ruanndias/nodejs-blog-tutorial/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:210
    throw new TypeError('app.use() requires a middleware function')
    ^

TypeError: app.use() requires a middleware function
    at Function.use (/home/ruanndias/nodejs-blog-tutorial/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:210:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ruanndias/nodejs-blog-tutorial/index.js:8:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:971:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1011:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:822:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:730:14)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1051:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:16:11
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `app.use(expressEdge.engine);` instead of `app.use(expressEdge);`

`express-edge` export a object like `module.exports = { config, engine };` and the  `engine` is a express middleware.

Comment: Thanks man, I really understand now my mistake!  I did, exactly what you said, and its running ! uhull :)

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs of `express-edge`:

```
const { engine } = require('express-edge');
app.use(engine);
```